# Find the column index by the maximum value of row in numpy

Tags: python, list, numpy

The following numpy is given:

```
myArray = np.array([[ 3, 8, 0, 0],
                    [ 9, 7, 8, 1],
                    [ 3, 8, 9, 7]])
```

Need to find the column index of each maximum value in a row.

That is, according to the above data should return the following list:

```
[1,0,2]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [np.argmax](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) function with `axis = 1` property which means finding *row* indices.

```
max_index_col = np.argmax(myArray, axis=1).tolist()
```

Output

```
>> max_index_col 
[1, 0, 2]
```